# characterised inventory matrix in multiLCA calculations with brightway

Tags: brightway

what does the characterised inventory matrix of a multiLCA object represent in Brightway2? I would have expected to find several of these matrices in the object, representing the characterised inventory of the different activities and different impact assessment methods.

For a simple LCA object, the sum of all the elements of the characterised inventory matrix gives the total impact of that activity. But it seems not to be the case for MultiLCA objects (e.g.)

```
#impact assessment method
i2002=[('IMPACT 2002+ (Endpoint)', 'resources', 'total'),
     ('IMPACT 2002+ (Endpoint)', 'climate change', 'climate change'),
     ('IMPACT 2002+ (Endpoint)', 'human health', 'total'),
     ('IMPACT 2002+ (Endpoint)', 'ecosystem quality', 'total')
      ]

fu=[]
for j in range(1,11):
    fu.append({bw.Database('ei_33c').random():1})
testsetup_i2002 ={'inv': fu, 'ia':i2002}
bw.calculation_setups['testsetup_i2002'] = testsetup_i2002
mlca_test=bw.MultiLCA('testsetup_i2002')

result=mlca_test.lca.characterized_inventory.sum()
```

the result is different from the scores or sum of scores obtained from

```
mlca_test.results()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the `MultiLCA` [source code](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-calc/src/9a8887757cdec533a14b16d1a4151b95fef8a97f/bw2calc/multi_lca.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), which is relatively simple. It overwrites the `characterized_inventory` matrix for each step of the calculation, and only stores the results in a Numpy array: `self.results = np.zeros((len(self.func_units), len(self.methods)))`. To get what you want - separate characterized inventory matrices for each combination of functional unit and LCIA method - you would have to write your own subclass. Here is one example:

```
from bw2calc.multi_lca import *


class PersistentMultiLCA(MultiLCA):
    def __init__(self, cs_name):
        if not calculation_setups:
            raise ImportError
        assert cs_name in calculation_setups
        try:
            cs = calculation_setups[cs_name]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(
                "{} is not a known `calculation_setup`.".format(cs_name)
            )
        self.func_units = cs['inv']
        self.methods = cs['ia']
        self.lca = LCA(demand=self.all, method=self.methods[0])
        self.lca.lci(factorize=True)
        self.method_matrices = []
        self.results = {}
        for method in self.methods:
            self.lca.switch_method(method)
            self.method_matrices.append(self.lca.characterization_matrix)

        for row, func_unit in enumerate(self.func_units):
            self.lca.redo_lci(func_unit)
            for col, cf_matrix in enumerate(self.method_matrices):
                self.lca.characterization_matrix = cf_matrix
                self.lca.lcia_calculation()
                self.results[row, col] = self.lca.characterized_inventory.copy()
```